# Rolling Over a Log File On Startup

Tags: java, json, configuration, log4j, rollingfileappender

I'm trying to set up log4j with a RollingRandomAccessFile. I have it set up to roll over when it exceeds 20 megabytes, and to roll over what's left over from the last run when it starts up. The size based policy works fine, but I can't get it to do anything with the startup policy. I've tried using JSON and XML for the config, and couldn't get it to work with either. Even trying to programmatically trigger it by calling

```
((RollingRandomAccessFileAppender)LoggerContext.getContext(false).getConfiguration().getAppender("LOGFILE")).getManager().rollover();
```

doesn't do anything. I set the status logger to output everything, and no message popped up during the startup indicating it was even making an attempt to roll the log file over. When using the previously mentioned programmatic method, it outputs a message saying it renamed the file to the appropriate name it should be before compression, but no such file is created, and no compressed file is mentioned or created. Here's the config for the appender in JSON:

```
"RollingRandomAccessFile": {

    "name": "LOGFILE",
    "append": "false",
    "fileName": "ServerData/logs/latest.log",
    "filePattern": "ServerData/logs/$${date:dd-MM-YYYY_(EEE)_HH-mm-ss-SSS(z)}.log.gz",
    "PatternLayout": {

      "pattern": "$${date:dd-MM-YYYY (EEE)::HH:mm:ss.SSS(z)}: [%t] %-5level %logger{36}: %m%n"

    },
    "Policies": {

      "OnStartupTriggeringPolicy": {},
      "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {"size": "20MB"}

    }


  }
```

Comment: According to the docs, [the target file's timestamp is compared with the JVM start time](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/OnStartupTriggeringPolicy.html). Have you checked if a log file is older than JVM's start time?

Comment: @Bilguun No it would appear not. I don't understand how that's possible though, since the file was created by a JVM that exited before the one currently executing. That being said it looks like my best option is to use the programmatic method, but that also isn't working for some reason.